# Breaking out of while loop with specific input

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop

I am currently trying to take user input and than break out of it when a condition is met (in this case would be 0). I got the loop working when the if statement is set to inp == ''. When an empty string is entered it breaks out. But if I change the criteria to anything other than '', say 0, the code doesn't break out of the loop.

```
while True:
    inp = input("Would you like to add a student name: ")
    if inp == 0:
        break
    student_name = input("Student name: ")
    student_id = input("Studend ID: ")
    add_student(student_name, student_id)
```

I have tried casting the 0 as an int but same issue arises...

EDIT: The above code loops without breaking.

FIX: input takes in a string and I was comparing it to an int. I needed to cast my 0 as a string so the types matched.

Comment: the `input()` function returns a string, and thus it will never be equal to integer 0.

Comment: Ahh I see my issue. I was casting the input as int without realizing the input itself was a string. Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, `input` always gives you a string. Two ways

```
inp = int(input("Would you like to add a student name: "))
if inp == 0:
```

or

```
inp = input("Would you like to add a student name: ")
if inp == '0':
```

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a `string` and will never be `==` to `0`, which is an `int`.
You can either cast (aka Type Conversion) `inp` to an `int` or the value to match (`0`) to a `string` (`'0'`) before comparison, i.e.:

```
if inp == str(0): # or simply inp == "0"
   ...
```

casting `inp` to an `int`:

```
if int(inp) == 0:
    ...
```

Comment: `str(0)` rather than `"0"`?

Answer (score 0):

You need `inp` to store the integer input, but `input()` by default stores a string

```
while True:
    inp = int(input("Would you like to add a student name: "))
    if inp == 0:
        break
    student_name = input("Student name: ")
    student_id = input("Studend ID: ")
    add_student(student_name, student_id)
```

Although, if you're asking them to indicate something, you should probably use `distutils.util.strtobool()`, which accepts a variety of inputs such as `0` or `n` or `no` to indicate no.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    inp = input("Would you like to add a student name: ")
    if len(inp) == 0 or inp =="": #checking the if the the length of the input is equal to 0 or is an empty string 
        break
    student_name = input("Student name: ")
    student_id = input("Studend ID: ")
    add_student = (student_name, student_id)

print ("The file list-{}.csv is created!".format("something"))
```

let me know if this what you want.
you can't use int because it will expect an integer if the length is not 0 and this is because object of type 'int' has no len.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of "if you give someone a fish, they'll have food a for a day", there's a reason we ask for a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example. You titled your question "breaking out of while loop", but that's not really the issue. The `break` statement isn't being executed, which should lead you to realize that the `if` condition is evaluating to `False`, so the Minimal Example would be "Why is `inp == 0` evaluating to `False`?", rather than the non-minimal "Why is this entire while loop not doing what I expected?" Simply paring a problem down to the smallest component can often be enough to solve a problem: if you had looked at value of `inp == 0` and seen that it's `False`, that should lead you to check the value of `inp` and see that it's `'0'` rather than `0`.